# chef server showing wrong IP address for bootstrapped nodes

Tags: chef-infra, configuration-management

I recently started studying chef and trying out with 3 nodes. I managed to set up my workstation on ubuntu (was not obvious) and bootstrapped 2 nodes for now. But below on this image their IP address is set to 127.0.0.1.

[image: chef server nodes tab]

I boostrapped them using this following method:

```
$knife bootstrap xxxx.xxxx.com -x root -P xxxxxxxx -N xxxxxxxx
```

It seems fine, it appears on chef server but when I do the following to force run the chef-client on it, it throws some errors as displayed below.

```
$ knife ssh "name:logsmanager" "chef-client" -x root -a xxxx.xxxx.com
FATAL: 1 node found, but does not have the required attribute to establish the connection. Try setting another attribute to open the connection using --attribute.
```

Besides , I understand that the client nodes check in every 30 minutes by default but on my chef server nodes tab, it shows last checked in 6 days ago and 13 hours ago.

Does that mean the client nodes don't check the chef server or it's like source versioning checkin, checkout terminology?

I would be grateful if anybody can she some lights on this for me. Thank you

**EDIT:**

After running the command above, I run into another issue:

```
$ knife ssh "name:logsmanager" "chef-client" -x root -a fqdn
WARNING: Failed to connect to my.domain.com -- Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user root@my.domain.com@my.domain.com .Seems to understant root@my.domain.com as username for my.domain.com fqdn.
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-a` argument to `knife ssh` should be a node attribute in the "dotted path" syntax so things like `fqdn` or `cloud.public_ipv4`. By default `knife ssh` will use the node's FQDN to connect to.

Knife will run the search quer you provide and then use the given attribute to look up which name to pass to `Net::SSH`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. I am afraid I didn't understand. I did provide a `fqdn` after -a attribute.

Comment: I mean literally `-a fqdn` (which is already the default). You are specifying which attribute to use, not a value.

Comment: I edited the post, It doesn't seem to be connecting.As well, I do not understand why the IP would be a local loopback

Comment: Check that the FQDN's are actually set correctly. As I said, `-a fqdn` is already the default so I wouldn't expect that to change anything. Try `-a ipaddress` perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

By default chef client is not checking changes on Chef server. It's done manually.

To make node run chef-client periodically check this option:

```
-i SECONDS, --interval SECONDS
The frequency (in seconds) at which the chef-client runs. When the chef-client is run at intervals, --splay and --interval values are applied before the chef-client run. Default value: 1800.
```

More info about other options for chef-client you can [find here](https://docs.chef.io/chef/chef_client.html).

About providing attribute, you must provide which attribute you want to use for SSH, not actual value. That means that:

```
$ knife ssh "role:web" "uptime" -x ubuntu -a public_hostname
```

public_hostname - represents node attribute called `public_hostname`